# (WSO2ESB) Is it possible to set off a Task from within a Sequence?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am looking to have a Sequence kick off a Task every time a message comes through (during its mediation).  For example:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="main">
   <in>
      **<task>
         <SOME_TASK_DETAILS_TO_START_OFF>
      </task>**
   </in>
   <out>
      <send></send>
   </out>
   <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
</sequence>
```

Is this actually possible?  All the documentation I've found seems to relate to tasks starting up with the ESB or through manual kickoff in the web console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this script inside your inSequence :

```
 <script language="js">importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse);
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.task);
    var sc = mc.getConfiguration();
    var task = sc.getStartup("TestTask");
    var td = task.getTaskDescription() 
    td.setCount(0);
    //td.setCron(null);
    task.setTaskDescription(td);            
    sc.updateStartup(task);
    mc.setConfiguration(sc);
    task.destroy();
    task.init(mc.getEnvironment());</script>
```

If your task has a Cron expression, with td.setCount(0), task execution stop and with td.setCount(-1), task execution restart.

With td.setCount(1) + td.setCron(null), when you edit your task in ESB Console, you can observe that definition has been updated : Trigger Type changed from 'Cron' to 'Simple' (with count=1 and interval=0). Definition is changed in memory and lost when you restart the ESB